# How can I get rid of the gap between my listview list items (android)

Tags: android

I'm trying to get rid of this 1px gap between lititems in my ListView. I know this is normally defined by the listview's `dividerHight` property. But this property was not set in my layout file.

Setting it to `0px` or `0.0dp` didn't help either. I may have caused these gaps somehow programmatically but I don't remember now.

By the way, I have 4 different view types, i.e. different listitem layouts. This should rule out the possiblity of the gap being defined in the listitem layout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this in xml:

```
android:divider="@null"
```

Or this from code:

```
yourListView.setDivider(null);
```